# DomDocument doesn't see <enclosure url=""/>

Tags: php, xml, rss, domdocument

I'm using a PHP script that retrieve RSS and sent it as JSON.

it began by

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($_GET['url']);
```

The feed I use looks like (URL: [RSS FEED](https://www.dealabs.com/rss/new.xml))

[image]

and has a nice  under .

I saw that I couldn't access to this data. In fact, when I 
    var_dump($feed);
I didn't see any notion of enclosure and no notion of https://MYURL.COM/MYPATH

So questions: WHY and HOW :-)

Thanks !

**EDIT:**

HERE is the full script and var dump content:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($_GET['url']);

$json = array();

$json['title'] =  $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['description'] = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
$json['link'] =  $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;


$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');
$json['items'] = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
   $json['items'][$i]['title'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $json['items'][$i]['description'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $json['items'][$i]['pubdate'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $json['items'][$i]['guid'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('guid')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   $json['items'][$i]['link'] = $item->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
   //$json['items'][$i]['url'] = $item->getELementsByTagName('nodeValue')->item(0)->firstChild->getAttribute('url');

    $i++;
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

VAR DUMP of $feed when https://www.dealabs.com/rss/new.xml url is passed in params (too long to be here): [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/UbgJdFrE)

Comment: Might be helpful to share the dump of $feed.

Comment: Please provide an example code that allows to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Devon I've updated the post!

Comment: @ThW I've updated the post!

Answer (score 0):

Just as a quick demo of how to use DOMDocument and fetching data from an XML document...

```
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($_GET['url']);

$xpath=new DOMXPath($feed);

foreach ( $xpath->query("//enclosure") as $enclosure ) {
    echo "Element=".$feed->saveXML($enclosure)."\n";
    var_dump($enclosure);
    echo "Url=".$enclosure->getAttribute("url")."\n";
}
```

As you can see, I'm using XPath to fetch the enclosure elements from the source and first printing the XML out (you have to use the document saveXML method to output the XML).  The The next line shows you what var_dump gives you - basically a lot of internal stuff which supports the DOM structure.  Lastly, the value of the url attribute is printed.

Using something like I could get from your sample data (always better to include the data rather than an image).  The output gives...

```
Element=<enclosure url="https://something/url"/>
/home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/XML/test2.php:13:
class DOMElement#3 (18) {
  public $tagName =>
  string(9) "enclosure"
  public $schemaTypeInfo =>
  NULL
  public $nodeName =>
  string(9) "enclosure"
  public $nodeValue =>
  string(0) ""
  public $nodeType =>
  int(1)
  public $parentNode =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $childNodes =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $firstChild =>
  NULL
  public $lastChild =>
  NULL
  public $previousSibling =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $nextSibling =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $attributes =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $ownerDocument =>
  string(22) "(object value omitted)"
  public $namespaceURI =>
  NULL
  public $prefix =>
  string(0) ""
  public $localName =>
  string(9) "enclosure"
  public $baseURI =>
  string(40) "/home/nigel/workspace/PHPTest/XML/t1.xml"
  public $textContent =>
  string(0) ""
}
Url=https://something/url
```

Answer (score 0):

No doubt you now have this worked out by now but if not perhaps the following might be useful.
Given the url below and a couple of small helper functions `getchild` and `getvalue` you can simply iterate through each `item` in the XML/RSS feed like this - choosing whatever attributes from `enclosure` you wish to capture. In reality you would more than likely want to make the helper functions more robust but you should get the idea.

```
define('BR','<br />');
$url='https://www.dealabs.com/rss/new.xml';

function getchild( $node,$index ){
    $child=$node->childNodes->item( $index );
    if( !$child )throw new Exception( __FUNCTION__ .' -> Unable to find child node',$index);
    return $child;
}
function getvalue( $node ){
    return $node->nodeValue;
}

try{

    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $dom=new DOMDocument;
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->validateOnParse = false;
    $dom->standalone=true;
    $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
    $dom->substituteEntities=true;
    $dom->recover=true;
    $dom->formatOutput=false;
    $dom->load( $url );

    $errors = libxml_get_errors();
    libxml_clear_errors();


    if( !empty( $errors ) ) {
        throw new Exception( implode( PHP_EOL, $errors ) );
    }

    $items=$dom->getElementsByTagName('item');

    if( !empty( $items ) ){

        foreach( $items as $index => $item ){
            try{

                $title=getvalue( getchild( $item, 0 ) );
                $link=getvalue( getchild( $item,1 ) );
                $description=getvalue( getchild( $item,2 ) );
                $content=getvalue( getchild( $item,3 ) );
                $guid=getvalue( getchild( $item,4 ) );
                $pubDate=getvalue( getchild( $item,5 ) );
                $enclosure=getchild( $item, 6 );

                $x=getvalue( getchild( $item, 69 ) );

                /* elected to get the url only but same method for other attributes */
                echo $enclosure->getAttribute('url').BR;

            }catch( Exception $e ){
                printf( 'Caught Exception: %s @ index %d<br />', $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode() );
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    $dom=null;
}catch( Exception $e ){
    printf( 'Caught Exception -> Trace:%s Message:%s Code:%d', $e->getTraceAsString(), $e->getMessage(), $e->getCode() );
}
```